# Route model binding in controller@index?

Tags: laravel, route-model-binding

I want to set up a route that fetches all `Contact`s associated with a `Customer`.  The endpoint would look like `/customers/{customer}/contacts` such that `{customer}` provides context for which contacts should be returned.  My `routes/web.php` looks like this:

```php
Route::get('/customers/{customer}/contacts', 'CustomerContactsController@index');
```

I generated the controller with `--model=Contact` specified.  As a result, several of the methods come with type hinting out of the box, but the `index()` method doesn't, and actually *won't* run at all with any parameters supplied.

From `CustomerContactsController.php`:

```php
public function index(Customer $customer)
{
    $this->authorize('update', $customer->account);

    $contacts = $customer->contacts;

    return view('contacts.index', compact('customer', 'contacts'));
}
```

This returns a completely blank screen.  The associated Blade view looks like this:

```php
@section('title')
{{ $customer->name }}
@endsection

@section('action')
    <a href="{{ $customer->path() . '/contacts/create' }}" class="button" >{{ __('Add New Contact') }}</a>
@endsection

@section('content')
<ul>
    @foreach ($contacts as $contact)   
        <li>{{ $contact->name }}</li> 
    @endforeach
</ul>
@endsection
```

I can still access the customer id inside the controller logic using `Route::current()->parameters['customer']`, but isn't there a better/easier way to do this?

Comment: Can you share your code at `CustomerContactsController@index`

Comment: ARGH! and here I was thinking something was wrong in the controller!  In supplying the view code, I realized that `contacts/index.blade.php` view was missing the `@extends ('layout')`  :( :(

Comment: did you try to `dd($contacts)`. actually, just check you getting data or not?

Answer (score 1):

Providing the `{customer}` parameter to the controller's `index()` method was the right way to go.  After posting this question, I stumbled across the term **nested resource controller** which *exactly* described what I wanted to accomplish.  In the help message for the `php artisan make:controller` command, I found the `-p` flag would do this for me.

I created a new controller using `php artisan make:controller --model=Contact --parent=Customer TestCustomerContactsController` and found that the only changes from my current controller were the exact changes *I was already making* to my existing controller.

The built-in debugging screen in Laravel was a red herring.  Without having `$customer` scoped to the method, Laravel would kick back an error (as it should).  With the variable properly scoped, the error message went away, but with a completely blank canvas it felt like I was going in the wrong direction entirely.

#### The fix

My `view` was full of `@section`s but without an `@extends` telling it which layout template to render to.  Without providing this directive, any code within `@section` blocks doesn't get rendered, which in my case was the entire view, returning an empty page.

#### Answering the other question

In case it wasn't clear from @Developer's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56488124/4468423), any `{parameter}` present in the `Route` URI is also available via `request()->parameter` in the controller.  E.g.

```php
// routes/web.php
Route::get('/customers/{customer}/contacts/{contact}', 'CustomerContactsController@show');

// CustomerContactsController.php
public method show()
{
    $customer_id = request()->customer;
    $contact_id = request()->contact;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you getting value from in controller try this

your route is

```
Route::get('/customers/{customer}/contacts', 'CouponsController@testing');
```

and

try this in your controller

```
public function testing(Request $req)
{
    dd($req->customer);
}
```

Comment: didn't think of that!  although it wasn't my problem, that's good to keep in mind for the future.  thanks!

Comment: hi @erich if you are using one more and go to function and ' , and use moled like create object and get value in function try this